# No me funciona el onclick luego del ingreso de usuario

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy haciendo un simulador de un buscador de autos con HTML en realidad son 2 html el index que tiene este ingreso, y panel.html que tiene el resto de la web. 1 css y 2 js.
Aca les dejo el index.html donde esta el ingreso.

```
  <body>
    <center><form action="">
        <label for="nombrePrincipal">Ingrese su Nombre:</label>
        <input type="text" id="nombrePrincipal" placeholder="Guille">
        <br>

        <label for="passPrincipal">Contraseña:</label>
        <input type="text" id="passPrincipal" placeholder="234">
        <br>
        <button id="boton" role="link" type="button" onclick= "entrar()"> Entrar</button>
        


    </form>
    </center>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Y ahora les paso el Javascript que uso para ese solo usuario y el boton que uso para el ingreso.

```
function entrar() {
  const usu = document.getElementById("usuarioPrincipal").value;
  const pass = document.getElementById("passPrincipal").value;
  console.log(usu, pass);

  if (usu == "Guille" && pass == "234") {
    window.location.href = "panel.html";
    localStorage.usuario = usu
  } else {
    alert("Error")
  }
}
```

No se en donde le estoy errando...
El boton cuando hago click no me lleva a ningun lado.
No llega al otro html... Gracias.

Comment: Veo un error en tu función, en tu constante "usu" seleccionas un id inexistente "usuarioPrincipal" en lugar de "nombrePrincipal", trata de cambiar eso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en el momento de seleccionar un ID inexistente en tu función, seleccionas `usuarioPrincipal` en lugar de `nombrePrincipal`, mira el ejemplo:

```js
function entrar() {
        const usu = document.getElementById("nombrePrincipal").value;
        const pass = document.getElementById("passPrincipal").value;
        console.log(usu, pass);
    if (usu == "Guille" && pass == "234") {
        window.location.href = "https://http.cat/404";
        localStorage.usuario = usu
    } else {
        alert("Error")
    } 
}
```

```html
<center>
        <form action="">
            <label for="nombrePrincipal">Ingrese su Nombre:</label>
            <input type="text" id="nombrePrincipal" placeholder="Guille">
            <br>

            <label for="passPrincipal">Contraseña:</label>
            <input type="text" id="passPrincipal" placeholder="234">
            <br>
            <button id="boton" role="link" type="button" onclick= "entrar()"> Entrar</button>
        </form>
    </center>
```

Comment: Si muchachos era eso. Me había bloqueado y no lo veía!!! Gracias.